# include external code

Tags: php, javascript

I have the below code to display date/time in my page. When I have the code written in my index.php it runs fine. when I try to call it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/clock.js">
```

Is not working.

Do I have to change anything? Thank you.

```
var weekdaystxt=["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

function showLocalTime(container, servermode, offsetMinutes, displayversion){
if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
this.container=document.getElementById(container)
this.displayversion=displayversion
var servertimestring=(servermode=="server-php")? '<? print date("D, F jS Y H:i:s", time())?>' : (servermode=="server-ssi")? '<!--#config timefmt="%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->' : '<%= Now() %>'
this.localtime=this.serverdate=new Date(servertimestring)
this.localtime.setTime(this.serverdate.getTime()+offsetMinutes*60*1000) //add user offset to server time
this.updateTime()
this.updateContainer()
}

showLocalTime.prototype.updateTime=function(){
var thisobj=this
this.localtime.setSeconds(this.localtime.getSeconds()+1)
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.updateTime()}, 1000) //update time every second
}

showLocalTime.prototype.updateContainer=function(){
var thisobj=this
if (this.displayversion=="long")
this.container.innerHTML='<? print date("D, F jS Y")?>'
else{
var hour=this.localtime.getHours()
var minutes=this.localtime.getMinutes()
var seconds=this.localtime.getSeconds()
var ampm=(hour>=12)? "PM" : "AM"
var dayofweek=weekdaystxt[this.localtime.getDay()]
this.container.innerHTML=formatField(hour, 1)+":"+formatField(minutes)+":"+formatField(seconds)+" (UTC +2)"
}
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.updateContainer()}, 1000) //update container every second
}

function formatField(num, isHour){
if (typeof isHour!="undefined"){ //if this is the hour field
var hour=(num>24)? num-24 : num
return (hour==0)? 24 : hour
}
return (num<=9)? "0"+num : num//if this is minute or sec field
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is the path to the script correct?

Comment: does that php code gets executed?

Comment: where do you call these js-functions?

Comment: How does it not work? did you check the browser's javascript console for errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors... I call the script inside head tag as all my scripts...

Comment: @j08691 if I add <script type="text/javascript"> in dreamweaver it shows me error in this line: 'if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return'

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a php expert but my it seems that since your clock.js is a javascript file and not a php file, the php code in there does not get interpreted (not sure if that's the right word).

Comment: @brains911 but if I put it inside <head> of my index.php as js it works fine!